# Android - Load image from gallery and set it as background of a layout

Tags: android, image, layout

I want to set loaded image as a background of a coordinator layout and apparently setImageBitmap() function allow only views like ImageView, textView etc to set loaded image as background. What should I do?

```
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri selectedBgImageUri = data.getData();
                if (selectedBgImageUri != null) {
                    try {
                        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedBgImageUri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        coordinatorLayout.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        selectedImagePath = getPathFromUri(selectedBgImageUri);

                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitmapDrawable to perform that

```java
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedBgImageUri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

Resources resources = getResources();
// Or if you are in fragment
// Resources resources = requireContext().getResources();

Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap);
coordinatorLayout.setBackground(drawable);
```